# CancelledError: RunManyGraphs while running distributed tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to distribute TensorBox ReInspect implementation (https://github.com/Russell91/TensorBox) over one ps and two workers. I have added the training code in a `sv.managed_session`.

```
def train(H, test_images, server):
'''
Setup computation graph, run 2 prefetch data threads, and then run the main loop
'''

if not os.path.exists(H['save_dir']): os.makedirs(H['save_dir'])

ckpt_file = H['save_dir'] + '/save.ckpt'
with open(H['save_dir'] + '/hypes.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(H, f, indent=4)

x_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
confs_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
boxes_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
q = {}
enqueue_op = {}
for phase in ['train', 'test']:
    dtypes = [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32]
    grid_size = H['grid_width'] * H['grid_height']
    shapes = (
        [H['image_height'], H['image_width'], 3],
        [grid_size, H['rnn_len'], H['num_classes']],
        [grid_size, H['rnn_len'], 4],
        )
    q[phase] = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=30, dtypes=dtypes, shapes=shapes)
    enqueue_op[phase] = q[phase].enqueue((x_in, confs_in, boxes_in))

def make_feed(d):
    return {x_in: d['image'], confs_in: d['confs'], boxes_in: d['boxes'],
            learning_rate: H['solver']['learning_rate']}

def thread_loop(sess, enqueue_op, phase, gen):
    for d in gen:
        sess.run(enqueue_op[phase], feed_dict=make_feed(d))

(config, loss, accuracy, summary_op, train_op,
 smooth_op, global_step, learning_rate, encoder_net) = build(H, q)

saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=None)
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(
    logdir=H['save_dir'],
    flush_secs=10
)

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()


#Assigning the first worker as supervisor 
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                         #logdir="/tmp/train_logs",
                         init_op=init_op,
                         summary_op=summary_op,
                         saver=saver,
                         global_step=global_step,
                         save_model_secs=600)

#Starting training in managed session distributed across the cluster
# with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
with sv.managed_session(server.target) as sess:
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    for phase in ['train', 'test']:
        # enqueue once manually to avoid thread start delay
        gen = train_utils.load_data_gen(H, phase, jitter=H['solver']['use_jitter'])
        d = gen.next()
        sess.run(enqueue_op[phase], feed_dict=make_feed(d))
        t = tf.train.threading.Thread(target=thread_loop,
                                      args=(sess, enqueue_op, phase, gen))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    tf.set_random_seed(H['solver']['rnd_seed'])
    # sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
    weights_str = H['solver']['weights']
    if len(weights_str) > 0:
        print('Restoring from: %s' % weights_str)
        saver.restore(sess, weights_str)

    # train model for N iterations
    start = time.time()
    max_iter = H['solver'].get('max_iter', FLAGS.iter)
    for i in xrange(max_iter):
        display_iter = H['logging']['display_iter']
        adjusted_lr = (H['solver']['learning_rate'] *
                       0.5 ** max(0, (i / H['solver']['learning_rate_step']) - 2))
        lr_feed = {learning_rate: adjusted_lr}

        if i % display_iter != 0:
            # train network
            batch_loss_train, _ = sess.run([loss['train'], train_op], feed_dict=lr_feed)
        else:
            # test network every N iterations; log additional info
            if i > 0:
                dt = (time.time() - start) / (H['batch_size'] * display_iter)
            start = time.time()
            (train_loss, test_accuracy, summary_str,
                _, _) = sess.run([loss['train'], accuracy['test'],
                                  summary_op, train_op, smooth_op,
                                 ], feed_dict=lr_feed)
            writer.add_summary(summary_str, global_step=global_step.eval(session=sess))
            print_str = string.join([
                'Step: %d',
                'lr: %f',
                'Train Loss: %.2f',
                'Test Accuracy: %.1f%%',
                'Time/image (ms): %.1f'
            ], ', ')
            print(print_str %
                  (i, adjusted_lr, train_loss,
                   test_accuracy * 100, dt * 1000 if i > 0 else 0))

        if global_step.eval(session=sess) % H['logging']['save_iter'] == 0 or global_step.eval(session=sess) == max_iter - 1:
            saver.save(sess, ckpt_file, global_step=global_step)
sv.stop()
```

The training starts but before printing the final iteration, I get the following error on the supervisor (worker:1):

```
W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:294] _0_fifo_queue: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed
W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:294] _1_fifo_queue_1: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "distributed-train.py", line 461, in thread_loop
    sess.run(enqueue_op[phase], feed_dict=make_feed(d))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 915, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 985, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
CancelledError: RunManyGraphs

*** Error in `python': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007f9a702b8eb0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 2):

The `CancelledError` is relatively benign: I suspect that your main thread exits the `with sv.managed_session() as sess:` block, which closes the session and cancels all pending requests, including those made by your two pre-fetching threads.

To avoid seeing this error, I'd recommend that you use the [`tf.train.Coordinator` and `tf.train.QueueRunner`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#coordinator-and-queuerunner) classes to manage the threads used for prefetching. These can ensure that you shut down the threads cleanly when the training ends. (In particular, there's an experimental [`FeedingQueueRunner`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6c5f8e4e013e54fed8dfcf49fb6de365f018022/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/dataframe/queues/feeding_queue_runner.py) that seems ideal for your application.)

The cause of the core dump is less clear, and it may reveal a bug in the session-closing or distributed session code. For that bug, can you please try to make a minimal example that reproduces the bug (without relying on any input data, etc.) and submit a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues)?